# Implementation of Python AES encryption/decryption code in Node JS

Tags: python, node.js, aes

I am trying to implement the following Python code in NodeJS:

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from functools import reduce
from Cryptodome.Hash import SHA256
from Cryptodome import Random
from binascii import b2a_hex

def encrypt(text, *params):
    key = createKey(*params)
    iv = Random.new().read(16)
    to_encrypt = _pad(text.encode('utf-8'))

    aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC,iv)
    result = aes.encrypt(to_encrypt)
    padded = result + iv
    hexed = b2a_hex(padded)
    return hexed.decode('utf-8')


def decrypt(encrypted, *params):
    try:
        hex_data = bytes.fromhex(encrypted)
    except Exception as e:
        print('fromhex failed: {}'.format(e))
        return encrypted
    iv = hex_data[-16:]
    to_decrypt = hex_data[:-16]

    aes = AES.new(createKey(*params), AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    result = aes.decrypt(to_decrypt)
    encrypt('Fname Snamne', '5b18f13dacef4a051745c895', '5b265df1acef4a4a1e9562fc', 'integrityCare')
    return _unpad(result).decode('utf-8')


def _unpad(s):
    return s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]


def createKey(*params):
    acc = reduce((lambda x, y: x + y), params)
    return SHA256.new((acc).encode('utf-8')).digest()


def _pad(s):
    pad = 16 - len(s) % 16
    newlen = len(s) + pad
    return s.ljust(newlen, bytes([pad]))
```

In other words I need NodeJS implementation of two functions: `encrypt` and `decrypt`.

Here are two tests to check whether the implementation is correct (Python code passes it):

Test 1:

```
decrypt('5b34bf12052364771da80b30bce3c986c610d26d3d9d1c8c41f755b45064fe48', '5b18f13dacef4a051745c895', '5b265df1acef4a4a1e9562fc', 'integrityCare')
Result: 'Fname Snamne'
```

Test 2:

```
decrypt(encrypt('Fname Snamne', '5b18f13dacef4a051745c895', '5b265df1acef4a4a1e9562fc', 'integrityCare'), '5b18f13dacef4a051745c895', '5b265df1acef4a4a1e9562fc', 'integrityCare')
Result: 'Fname Snamne'
```

There is a very popular NodeJS package for AES [aes-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aes-js), I just can't get the correct implementation of the functions above on NodeJS.